# Increase performance in Android OpenCV project

Tags: android, opencv, opengl-es, computer-vision, multicore

I'm developing money recognition system for blind people based on android mobile phone. For this I'm using OpenCV as image processing framework. I implemented a square detection module and it's working perfectly.

The phone camera releases 30 frames per second, so the processing is really slow. I use a canny edge detection algorithm (for square detection). The output result is drawn in `Android SurfaceView`. Any suggestion to speed this up? What about replacing `SurfaceView` with `GLSurfaceView`? Will it increase speed?

my device has dual core processor. **how about multi core programming??(for android)**

My device is Samsung Galaxy S2.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, SurfaceView is only used for software rendering.  You should consider using OpenGL in order to achieve hardware acceleration.

Comment: hardware acceleration,the exact point i want to know. will it help in this kind of Situation??

Comment: As @Astor said, it will help you only if the performance loss is related with the rendering, otherwise you should improve the image processing code.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to say if OpenGL will highly increase speed (yes, OpenGL is definitely faster).

Why don't you benchmark your application to find out how much time spents on drawing and on OpenCV computation?

For example:

- load one image and make OpenCV computations for **n** times (without displaying it)
- load the same image and display it **n** times

Compare results. If OpenCV takes (about) 80% of time then you definitely have to improve your OpenCV algorithm. Otherwise try to show image using OpenGL.